# Abort a read() from another thread

Tags: linux, posix

My main thread looks like this:

```
while (!shouldExit) {
   int c = getchar();
   switch (c) {
     case .... :
     case .... :
     case 'x' : shuoldExit = true; break;
   }
}
```

Then , there is another thread that reads data from the network, and when I get a special command it sets `shouldExit = 1`. This works perfectly, the only problem is that `getchar()` according to `strace` keeps blocking on `read(0)`.

How can my working thread abort the `read` system call in the main thread?

I tried sending signals to myself, but that just kills the application (expected). When I trap the signals in a null handler the app keeps alive, but the `read` keeps blocking.

One option might be to use `select()` , but I am not happy about it. Any alternatives?

**EDIT:**
See also this question, which is similar to mine, but we are searching for different solutions. His solution is not applicable to my problem, as the blocking `read()` is on the main thread.

[aborting a blocking read on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211834/aborting-a-blocking-read-on-linux)

Comment: when I call `kill(myPid,SIGINT)` my application just dies. Almost :)

Comment: you want to send that to the thread

Comment: signals are sent to processes, not thread. "The signal disposition is a per-process attribute: in a multithreaded application, the disposition of a particular signal is the same for all threads. ". From: http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Comment: in that page you'll see a link to http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill

Comment: You say that I should kill my `main()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pthread_kill() on the thread you want to signal. Don't use kill(); for that matter, since you linked to it, don't use signal() -- it's one of the more retarded, non-portable interfaces:

> The  behavior  of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
>   varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its
>   use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below."

[ This has been answered in the comments, but for some reason still shows up in the relevance top of unanswered questions. So here, for the sake of completeness ]

Comment: mmm... yes, but this solution is also ugly, since it will loose allocated memory on my working thread. I want to "signal" that thread, so it can do its own garbage collection.

Comment: pthread_kill() doesn't kill. It sends a signal. You don't have to send SIGINT, you can use any signal. And in any case kill() and pthread_kill() only "kill" when you haven't set a handler. To set the **signal handler** for the thread, use sigaction(). Also use pthread_sigmask() to select which thread receives the signal. Read up on the man pages for pthread_kill(), pthread_sigmask() and sigaction().